Laravel 419 Error on Login Request Despite XSRF-TOKEN Present in Cookies
I’m building a Laravel 11 application and handling login requests with Axios. I'm encountering a 419 error when trying to log in, even though the laravel-session and XSRF-TOKEN cookies are present in my browser’s developer tools under the Application tab.
// Fetch CSRF token before making HTTP requests
const getCsrfToken = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
  return response;
};

const getCookie = (name) => {
  const cookies = document.cookie.split("=");
  return cookies[1];
};

const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    await getCsrfToken(); // Ensure CSRF token is fetched

    // Now make the login request
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/login",
      {
        email,
        password,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          accept: "application/json",
          "X-XSRF-TOKEN": getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN"), // Retrieve the CSRF token
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    if (response.status === 200) {
      checkAuth(); // Call checkAuth only if login was successful
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during login:", error);
  }
};

Here’s my cors.php config for allowed origins:
'paths' => ['*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

My .env file includes the following configuration:
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

Expected behavior:
I expect the login request to be authenticated properly using the CSRF token from the cookies.
Actual behavior:
The request fails with a 419 status code, indicating a CSRF token mismatch, despite the XSRF-TOKEN and laravel-session being present in the cookies.

Does getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN") return a valid result? You seem to read the csrf-cookie but not saving it to cookies in getCsrfToken.

@parapente It does. getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN") returns this long key that does show up in my inspect tools.

Your JavaScript function for getting the CSRF token might not be correctly parsing the cookies. The function you provided splits on =, which can be an issue if there's more than one cookie.

@HassaanAli Could it be because laravel has my auth routes in web.php and not api.php. All my routes for api requests need to go in api.php right?

That's correct but you also needs to update your getCookie method, fix that and it should fix the problem.

Changed your .env file like this
APP_URL=http://localhost
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:3000

change your cors.php file like this
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

You can define your axios http client request headers globally instead of using like the request vis like this.
Note: You can add this in you main component in your front-end at top-level
    axios.defaults.baseURL = your_front_end_base_url  // ex: if you are using vite add  this `import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL`
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] = 'application/json'

